# Specifying arguments of HuggingFaceHub

Tags: python, nlp, language-model, huggingface

In this [tutorial](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/huggingface_hub), when specifying

```
llm = HuggingFaceHub(
    repo_id=repo_id, model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.5, "max_length": 64})
```

only repository id is mentioned, without referring to the task that is to be performed (for instance summarization or text generation). However, one may specify something like

```
dotaks = transformers.pipeline(
    model=repo_id, 
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    task='text-generation',
    return_full_text=True,
    temperature=0.5,
    max_new_tokens=124,)
```

If I try to remove the task it would not work. What is the difference among the above two approaches? How will the top code decide on the appropriate task if not specified?